# Can I setup safe surfing in Epiphany?

Tags: internet-browser

I have Elementary installed and created an account for my son. I went into parental controls as admin hoping I could set restrictions for him on browsing or searches. There is nothing there other than adding restricted sites. 
How can I make the surfing experience a safe one, other than me sitting there the entire time.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at Parental Controls in the system settings. You can restrict the use of epiphany but you have to manually enter websites that cannot be accessed. It's not perfect, but it's there.